# m2eclipse can't resolve archetypes from nexus

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, nexus

in our company we're using a local nexus repository. If I now try to create a new Maven project using the eclipse project wizard (M2Eclipse 0.12.1 installed) I allways get an 503 error from nexus.

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact
    at org.maven.ide.eclipse.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:577)
    at org.maven.ide.eclipse.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.resolveArchetype(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:526)
    at org.maven.ide.eclipse.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createArchetypeProject(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:437)
    at org.maven.ide.eclipse.wizards.MavenProjectWizard$5.runInWorkspace(MavenProjectWizard.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
    Contains: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.0-alpha-4 from/to nexus (http://vm-nexus-slx.heuboe.hbintern:8080/nexus/content/groups/public): Failed to transfer http://vm-nexus-slx.heuboe.hbintern:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0-alpha-4/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0-alpha-4.pom. Error code 503, Service Unavailable
    org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.0-alpha-4 from/to nexus (http://vm-nexus-slx.heuboe.hbintern:8080/nexus/content/groups/public): Failed to transfer http://vm-nexus-slx.heuboe.hbintern:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0-alpha-4/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0-alpha-4.pom. Error code 503, Service Unavailable
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$3.wrap(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:1413)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$3.wrap(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:1404)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:895)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:889)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector.get(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:276)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:438)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:214)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:296)
        at org.maven.ide.eclipse.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:555)
        at org.maven.ide.eclipse.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.resolveArchetype(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:526)
        at org.maven.ide.eclipse.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createArchetypeProject(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:437)
        at org.maven.ide.eclipse.wizards.MavenProjectWizard$5.runInWorkspace(MavenProjectWizard.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.TransferException: Failed to transfer http://vm-nexus-slx.heuboe.hbintern:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0-alpha-4/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0-alpha-4.pom. Error code 503, Service Unavailable
```

Resolving 'normal' artifacts works fine either using the integrated build or running install as "run-as" task.

I'm short before going nuts on this problem.

All ideas welcome.

Thx in advance

JayBee

Comment: Anything interesting going on in the nexus logs?

Comment: No nexus logs. Creating a maven project from the command line works. Looks like a problem on eclipse (3.6) or m2eclipse side.

Comment: If you visit `http://vm-nexus-slx.heuboe.hbintern:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0-alpha-4/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0-alpha-4.pom` in a browser does it work?

Comment: Yep, reading the URL with a browser works, even if I use the build-in browser of eclipse.

Comment: Is it just you, or is it all users? Can you try setting the Global Repository to 'Full Index Enabled' (in the 'Maven Repositories' view)

Comment: Tested it with a collegue. He has the same problem. 'Full Index Enabled' doesn't help too. Does m2eclipse use a different way to resolve archetypes than maven directly ?  Are differen security credentials needed ?

Comment: Just found the following waring in my nexus.log. `2011-06-07 16:30:00 WARN  [http-8080-48   ] - o.a.c.h.HttpMethodB~          - Cookie rejected: "$Version=0; rememberMe=deleteMe; $Path=/nexus". Illegal path attribute "/nexus". Path of origin: "/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/%E2%80%8Cmaven-archetype-quickstart/1.0-alpha-4/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0-alpha-4.pom"`
Does this give any clue ?

Comment: That `%E2%80%8C` doesn't look so good. The bytes decode as 'U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER'. Have you done any customization to the nexus config?

Comment: I'm just asking my colleques whether we have done customizations to the config. It semlls a little bit like an encoding problem. Do you have any hint where that could come from or where to look ?

Comment: No idea. Maybe an XML file that got auto-formatted somehow, and put in a newline where it shouldn't have? Just clutching at straws here.

Comment: A new clue from one of my collegues. He enabled the debug for maven and got the following output: `08.06.11 11:10:56 MESZ: 
08.06.11 11:10:56 MESZ: [DEBUG] Using connector AsyncRepositoryConnector with priority 100 for http://vm-nexus-slx.heuboe.hbintern:8080/nexus/content/groups/public as admin via www-proxy:8000 as null
08.06.11 11:10:56 MESZ: Downloaded http://vm-nexus-slx.heuboe.hbintern:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/cxf/cxf-http-basic/2.1.3/cxf-http-basic-2.1.3.pom`. It seems that m2eclipse uses our proxy without considering the configured bypasses.

Comment: Have you got the same proxy config in your .m2/settings.xml and Eclipse?

Comment: Yes. I think I figured it out so far. The SimpleAsyncHttpClient which is used does not consider the bypasses. If I disable the proxy in .m2/settings.xml it works !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I figured out so far that it seems, that m2eclipse is using the proxy specified in .m2/settings.xml but if relolving an archetype it ignores the nonProxyHosts.

I submitted a Bug-Report to the m2eclipse projekt: 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=348893

Thx for the help.

Answer (score 1):

We (my team, that is) also get this issue. Command line Maven works like a charm, in Eclipse we get a red wall by Maven (we proxy all dependencies through our Nexus).

I have however noticed, that once I set m2eclipse in Offline mode, it finds all dependencies. Since I often build in command line, resolving new dependencies this way is not an issue for me (it still might annoying for some).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Maven

Uncheck the option - Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories.

This should take care of the problem.